# Signature generator with upload does not work

Tags: php, generator, signature

Hey, i just wanted to know if you guys know why this does not work.

http://www.anitard.org/siggen/siggen_stripes/

When you've uploaded an image the script gets the file path from the form and then when you press create a signature is supposed to appear with the image you uploaded, but it doesn't!

If anyone know what the problem is, please let me know.

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Signature Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
      <div style="float:left;  width: 280px; margin-right: 3px;">
<form name="frm" method="post">


<p></p>
<p>Enter Text: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input name="user" type="text" size="20" class="textbox">
<br /><br />
<p> Color: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
  <select name="color2">
    <option value="color_standard">Standard</option>
    <option value="color_blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="color_lightblue">Light blue</option>
    <option value="color_red">Red</option>
    <option value="color_yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="color_green">Green</option>
    <option value="color_purple">Purple</option>
  </select>
  <br /><br />

<i><font size="1" face="verdana">Choose if your going to use one of our "anime" pictures or upload your own image.</font></i>

<br />

<script type="text/javascript">

function annClick() 
{
document.getElementById('butta').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('strup').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('namez').disabled = false;
}


function ownClick() 
{
document.getElementById('butta').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('strup').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('namez').disabled = true;
}

</script>


<input type="radio" name="checktype" id="ann" onclick="javascript:annClick();" value="1"> Anime<br>
<input type="radio" name="checktype" id="own" onclick="javascript:ownClick();" value="2"> Upload<br>

<br />

    &nbsp;<u>Anime</u><br /> 

<select name="anime" id="namez" size="9" disabled="true" onclick="document.getElementById( 'imgUpload' ).src=this.value+'.png';" />
        <option value="hack_twillight">.hack//Legend of the Twilight Bracelet</option>
        <option value="hack_roots">.hack//Roots</option>
                <option value="hack_sign">.hack//SIGN</option>
                <option value="07_ghost">07-Ghost</option>
                <option value="12_kingdoms">12 kokuki ( 12 kingdoms )</option>
                <option value="afro_samurai">Afro Samurai</option>
                <option value="ah_my_goddess">Ah! My Goddess</option>
                <option value="ai_yori_aoshi">Ai yori Aoshi</option>
                <option value="ai_yori_aoshi_enishi">Ai yori Aoshi ~enishi~</option>
                <option value="air_gear">Air Gear </option>
                <option value="air_tv">Air TV</option>
                <option value="aishiteru_ze_baby">Aishiteru ze Baby</option>
                <option value="akagi">Akagi</option>
                <option value="akikan">Akikan!</option>
                <option value="allison_to_lillia">Allison to Lillia</option>
                <option value="amaenaideyo">Amaenaideyo</option>
                <option value="amaenaideyo_katsu">Amaenaideyo Katsu</option>
                <option value="amatsuki">Amatsuki</option>                
                <option value="angel_heart">Angel heart</option>
                <option value="angelic_layer">Angelic layer</option>
                <option value="antique_bakery">Antique bakery</option>
                <option value="aria_the_animation">ARIA The animation</option>
                <option value="aria_the_natural">ARIA The natural</option>
                <option value="aria_the_origination">ARIA The origination</option>
                <option value="asu_no_yoichi">Asu no yoichi</option>
                <option value="ayakashi">Ayakashi</option>
                <option value="azumanga_daioh">Azumanga daioh</option>     
                <option value="baccano">Baccano</option>
                <option value="bakuretsu_tenshi">Bakuretsu Tenshi</option>
                <option value="bamboo_blade">Bamboo blade</option>
                <option value="basilisk">Basilisk</option>
                <option value="berserk">Berserk</option>
                <option value="basquash">Basquash</option>
                <option value="beck">Beck</option>
                <option value="black_cat">Black Cat</option>
                <option value="black_lagoon">Black Lagoon</option>
                <option value="black_lagoon_the_second_barrage">Black Lagoon the second barrage</option>                
                <option value="bleach">Bleach</option>
                <option value="blood">Blood+</option>
                <option value="bokura_ga_ita">Bokura ga ita</option>
                <option value="bokura_no">Bokura no</option>
                <option value="bokusatsu_tenshi_dokuro_chan">Bokusatsu tenshi dokuro chan</option>
                <option value="bokusatsu_tenshi_dokuro_chan_second.png">Bokusatsu tenshi dokuro chan 2</option>
                <option value="bounen_no_xamd">Bounen no xamd</option>
                <option value="busou_renkin">Busou renkin</option>
                <option value="canvas2">Canvas 2</option>
                <option value="capeta">Capeta</option>
                <option value="card_captor_sakura">Card captor sakura</option>
                <option value="casshern_sins">Casshern sins</option>
                <option value="chaos_head">Chaos head</option>
                <option value="chis_sweet_home">Chi's sweet home</option>
                <option value="chobits">Chobits</option>
                <option value="chocotto_sister">Choccotto_sister</option>
                <option value="chrno_crusade">Chrno crusade</option>
                <option value="clannad">Clannad</option>                
                <option value="claymore">Claymore</option>
                <option value="cluster_edge">Cluster edge</option>
                <option value="code_geass">Code geass</option>
                <option value="code_geass_r2">Code geass R2</option>
                <option value="cosplay_complex">Cosplay complex</option>
                <option value="cowbow_bebop">Cowboy bebop</option>
                <option value="crayon_shin_chan">Crayon shin chan</option>
                <option value="cross_game">Cross game</option>
                <option value="d_gray_man">D.Gray Man</option>
                <option value="dn_angel">DN Angel</option>
                <option value="da_capo">Da capo</option>                
                <option value="da_capo_ii">Da capo II</option>
                <option value="darker_than_black">Darker than black</option>
                <option value="dears">DearS</option>
                <option value="death_note">Death note</option>
                <option value="dennou_coil">Dennou coil</option>
                <option value="desert_punk">Desert punk</option>
                <option value="devil_may_cry">Devil may cry</option>
                <option value="doujin_work">Doujin work</option>
                <option value="dragon_ball">Dragon ball</option>  
                <option value="dragon_ball_gt">Dragon ball GT</option>                
                <option value="dragon_ball_z">Dragon ball Z</option>
                <option value="dragonaut_the_resonance">Dragonaut -the resonance-</option>
                <option value="fate_stay_night">Fate/stay night</option>
                <option value="final_approach">Final approach</option>
                <option value="flame_of_recca">Flame of recca</option>
                <option value="flcl">FLCL</option>
                <option value="fruits_basket">Fruits basket</option>
                <option value="full_metal_panic">Full metal panic</option>
                <option value="full_metal_panic_second_raid">Full metal panic secondn raid</option>  
                <option value="full_metal_panic_fumoffu">Full metal panic fumoffu</option>  
                <option value="full_moon_wo_sagashite">Full moon wo sagashite</option>                
                <option value="fullmetal_alchemist">Fullmetal alchemist</option>
                <option value="fullmetal_alchemist_brotherhood">Fullmetal alchemist brotherhood</option>
                <option value="fushigi_yuugi">Fushigi yuugi</option>
                <option value="h20">H2O ~footprints in the sand~</option>
                <option value="haibane_renmei">Haibane renmei</option>
                <option value="hajime_no_ippo">Hajime no ippo</option>
                <option value="hana_yori_dango">Hana yori dango</option>
                <option value="hanasakeru_seishonen">Hanasakeru seishonen</option>
                <option value="hanaukyo_maids">Hanaukyo maids</option>  
                <option value="hanaukyo_maids_le_verite">Hanaukyo maids le verite</option>  
                <option value="hanbun_no_tsukai">Hanbun no tsukai</option>  
                <option value="hand_maid_may">Hand maid may</option>                
                <option value="happiness">Happiness</option>
                <option value="happy_lesson">Happy lesson</option>
                <option value="hatsukoi_limited">Hatsukoi limited</option>
                <option value="hayate_no_gotoku">Hayate no gotoku</option>
                <option value="hayate_no_gotoky_2">Hayate no gotoku 2</option>
                <option value="he_is_my_master">He is my master</option>
                <option value="hellsing">Hellsing</option>
                <option value="heroic_age">Heroic Age</option>
                <option value="hetalia_axis_powers">Hetalia axis powers</option>  
                <option value="hidamari_sketch">Hidamari sketch</option>  
                <option value="hidamari_sketch_x365">Hidamari sketch x365</option>  
                <option value="high_school_girls">High school girls ( Girls high )</option>  
                <option value="higurashi_no_naku_koro_ni">Higurashi no naku koro ni</option>  
                <option value="higurashi_no_naku_koro_ni_kai">Higurashi no naku koro ni kai</option>
                <option value="higurashi_no_naku_koro_ni_rei">Higurashi no naku koro ni rei</option>
                <option value="hikaru_no_go">Hikaru no go</option>
                <option value="himawari">Himawari</option>
                <option value="himitsu_the_revelation">Himitsu the revelation</option>
                <option value="honey_and_clover">Honey and clover</option>
                <option value="honey_and_clover2">Honey and clover 2</option>
                <option value="hunter_x_hunter">Hunter x hunter</option>
                <option value="hyakko">Hyakko</option>  
                <option value="k_on">K-on</option>  
                <option value="kaiba">Kaiba</option>  
                <option value="kaleido_star">Kaleido star</option>                
                <option value="kamen_no_maid_guy">Kamen no maid guy</option>
                <option value="kamisama_kazoku">Kamisama kazoku</option>
                <option value="kannagi">Kannagi</option>
                <option value="kanokon">Kanokon</option>
                <option value="kanon">Kanon</option>
                <option value="karin">Karin</option>
                <option value="kasimasi">Kasimasi</option>
                <option value="katekyo_hitman_reborn">Katekyo hitman reborn</option>
                <option value="kaze_no_stigma">Kaze no stigma</option>  
                <option value="kekkaishi">Kekkaishi</option>  
                <option value="kemono_no_souja_erin">Kemono no souja erin</option>  
                <option value="kenichi">Kenichi</option>  
                <option value="kiba">Kiba</option>  
                <option value="kiddy_grade">Kiddy grade</option>
                <option value="kimi_ga_nozomu_eien">Kimi ga nozomu eien</option>
                <option value="kimikiss_pure_rouge">Kimikiss pure rouge</option>
                <option value="kirarin_revolution">Kirarin revolution</option>
                <option value="kodomo_no_jikan">Kodomo no jikan</option>
                <option value="koharu_biyori">Koharu biyori</option>
                <option value="koihime_musou">Koihime Musou</option>
                <option value="kurenai">Kurenai</option>  
                <option value="kurogane_no_linebarrel">Kurogane no linebarell</option>  
                <option value="kurokami">Kurokami</option>  
                <option value="kuroshitsuji">Kuroshitsuji</option>                
                <option value="kyo_kara_maoh">Kyo kara maoh</option>
                <option value="kurozuka">Kurozuka</option>
                <option value="kyouran_kazoku_nikki">Kyouran kazoku nikki</option>
                <option value="nabari_no_ou">Nabari no ou</option>
                <option value="nana">Nana</option>
                <option value="naruto">Naruto</option>
                <option value="naruto_shippuuden">Naruto shippuuden</option>
                <option value="natsu_no_arashi">Natsu no arashi</option>
                <option value="natsume_yuujinchou">Natsume yuujinchou</option>  
                <option value="zoku_natsume_yuujinchou">Zoku natsume yuuijinchou</option>  
                <option value="negima">Negima!?</option>  
                <option value="neo_angelique_abyss">Neo angelique abyss</option>  
                <option value="neon_genesis_evangelion">Neon genesis evangelion</option>  

                <option value="nhk_ni_youkoso">Nhk ni youkoso</option>  
                <option value="night_head_genesis">Night head genesis</option>  
                <option value="ninja_scroll">Ninja scroll</option>  
                <option value="nodame_cantabile">Nodame cantabile</option>
                <option value="nodame_cantabile_paris">Nodame cantabile paris</option>
                <option value="noein">Noein</option>
                <option value="noir">Noir</option>
                <option value="queens_blade">Queens blade</option>
                <option value="ragnarok">Ragnarok</option>
                <option value="rahxephon">RahXephon</option>
                <option value="ranma">Ranma ½</option>  
                <option value="real_drive">RD sennou chosashitsu</option>  
                <option value="read_or_die">Read or die</option>  
                <option value="rec">REC</option>                
                <option value="rental_magica">Rental magica</option>
                <option value="ristorante_paradiso">Ristorante paradiso</option>
                <option value="rizelmine">Rizelmine</option>
                <option value="romeo_x_juliet">Romeo x juliet</option>
                <option value="rosario_to_vampire">Rosario to vampire</option>
                <option value="rozen_maiden">Rozen maiden</option>
                <option value="rurouni_kenshin">Rurouni kenshin</option>
                <option value="tactical_roar">Tactical roar</option>
                <option value="tale_of_abyss">Tale of abyss</option>  
                <option value="tales_of_symphonia">Tales of symphonia</option>  
                <option value="tears_to_tiara">Tears to tiara</option>  
                <option value="gurren_lagann">Tengen toppa gurren lagann</option>  
                <option value="tenjou_tenge">Tnjou tenge</option>  
                <option value="tenshi_na_konamaiki">Tenshi na konamaiki</option>  
                <option value="birdy">Tetsuwan birdy decode</option>  
                <option value="tsukiyomi_moon_phase">Tsukiyomi moon phase</option>  
                <option value="index">To aru majutsu no index</option>
                <option value="to_love_ru">To love ru</option>
                <option value="today_in_class_5_2">Today in class 5-2</option>
                <option value="toshokan_sensou">Toshokan sensou</option>
                <option value="tokyo_mew_mew">Tokyo mew mew</option>
                <option value="toradora">Toradora</option>
                <option value="touch">Touch</option>
                <option value="trigun">Trigun</option>  
                <option value="trinity_blood">Trinity blood</option>  
                <option value="true_tears">True tears</option>  
                <option value="tsubasa_chronicles">Tsubasa chronicles</option>                
                <option value="utawarerumono">Utawarerumono</option>
    </select>

<br />
 <br /><br />

   <input type="submit" class="button" value="Create">
   <br />
</p>
</form>
<br />
<table width="364" height="112" border="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td width="350">

<?php


              if (isset($_REQUEST['anime']) && !empty($_REQUEST['anime'])) {



echo "<a href=\"download.php?file=sig.php?user=".$_REQUEST['user']."&anime=".$_REQUEST['anime']."&color2=".$_REQUEST['color2']."\"><img type=\"image\" width=\"350\" height=\"100\" border=\"0\" src=\"sig.php?user=".$_REQUEST['user']."&anime=".$_REQUEST['anime']."&color2=".$_REQUEST['color2']."\" /></a>";



            } elseif (isset($_REQUEST['animeinput']) && !empty($_REQUEST['animeinput'])) {

echo "<a href=\"sig.php?user=".$_REQUEST['user']."&anime=".substr($_REQUEST['animeinput'],0,15)."&color2=".$_REQUEST['color2']."\"><img type=\"image\" width=\"350\" height=\"100\" border=\"0\" src=\"sig.php?user=".$_REQUEST['user']."&anime=".substr($_REQUEST['animeinput'],0,15)."&color2=".$_REQUEST['color2']."\" /></a>";




            }







?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>






<div style="float:left;">

<script type="text/javascript">



// description : upload the image to the server
// notes : 1. open a new window
// 2. submit the form to it
function UploadImage()
{
window.open("","upload_image");
document.getElementById( 'frmUpload' ).target="upload_image";
document.getElementById( 'frmUpload' ).submit();
}

// description : set the src of the image to the uploaded one
function SetImageFile( pImgSrc )
{
document.getElementById( 'imgUpload' ).src=pImgSrc;

}


function setInputFile( pSRC )
{
document.frm.animeinput.value=pSRC;

}

</script>
<form action="<?php echo $_server['php-self'];  ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="something" class="uniForm">
        <input name="new_image" id="new_image" size="20" type="file" class="fileUpload" />
        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="submitButton">Upload</button>
<br />
<br />
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<em><font size="1" face="verdana">Preview of your picture/anime picture </font></em><br />
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table width="270" height="67" style="border:1px solid;">
  <tr>
<td width="270" height="67">
<img src="loading.gif" name="imgUpload" width="270" height="67" border="0" id="imgUpload">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
          if (isset ($_FILES['new_image'])){
              $imagename = $_FILES['new_image']['name'];
              $source = $_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'];
              $target = "temporary_images/".$imagename;
              move_uploaded_file($source, $target);

              $imagepath = $imagename;
              $save = "temporary_images/" . $imagepath; //This is the new file you saving
              $file = "temporary_images/" . $imagepath; //This is the original file

              list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 

              $modwidth = 350;                         
              $modheight = 100; 

              $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ; 
              $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
              imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ; 

              imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100) ; 

              $save = "temporary_images/sml_" . $imagepath; //This is the new file you saving
              $file = "temporary_images/" . $imagepath; //This is the original file

              list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 

              $modwidth = 80; 
              $modheight = 100; 

              $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ; 
              $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
              imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ; 

              imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100) ; 
echo "Large image: <img src='temporary_images/".$imagepath."'><br>"; 
echo "<form>";
echo '<input type="text" value="' .$imagepath. '" name="animeinput" id="animeinput" size="20" class="textbox">'; 
echo "</form>";
          }
        }
?>

<?php
// Define the folder to clean
// (keep trailing slashes)
$captchaFolder  = 'temporary_images/';

// Filetypes to check (you can also use *.*)
$fileTypes      = '*.jpg';

// Here you can define after how many
// minutes the files should get deleted
$expire_time    = 1; 

// Find all files of the given file type
foreach (glob($captchaFolder . $fileTypes) as $Filename) {

    // Read file creation time
    $FileCreationTime = filectime($Filename);

    // Calculate file age in seconds
    $FileAge = time() - $FileCreationTime; 

    // Is the file older than the given time span?
    if ($FileAge > ($expire_time * 60)){

        // Now do something with the olders files...

        print "The file $Filename is older than $expire_time minutes\n";
        unlink($Filename);

        // For example deleting files:
        //unlink($Filename);
    }

}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked for me in Chrome, though the layout was messed up

Comment: @Greg, are you sure? When you pressed create, did your uploaded image become a signature? because when i press create after uploading an image in firefox nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="urlhere.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: What url am i supposed to type?

Comment: whichever is the one that handles the post